# Is there an equivalent of Perl's URI.pm for C# / .NET?

Tags: c#, .net, perl, uri

.NET has the [Uri class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri_members.aspx).

Perl has its [URI module](http://search.cpan.org/dist/URI).

The major difference is that URI.pm allows you to **retrieve the query string components as a hash**, and **set a hash into the URI to construct a nice URI with query arguments**. I don't see anything like that on the .NET side. Is there some hidden class I don't know about?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer, apparently is "No". There is no built-in class in the .NET framework that can take a collection of names and values and produce a query string or allow you to directly modify the query string component of a URI as if it were a collection.

Answer (score 3):

Another utility provides for parsing query strings: [System.Web.HttpUtility.ParseQueryString()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httputility.parsequerystring.aspx) - Parses a query string into a NameValueCollection.

An example from [HttpUtility doc](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httputility.aspx):

```
String querystring;
...
// Parse the query string variables into a NameValueCollection.
NameValueCollection qscoll = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(querystring);

// Iterate through the collection.
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
foreach (String s in qscoll.AllKeys)
{
    sb.Append(s + " - " + qscoll[s] + "<br />");
}
```

Comment: Right, I can use this other string to parse a query string, but how do I put it back? Starting with a collection, there doesn't appear to be a facility for getting a query string.

Comment: Sorry, seems like you have to iterate through the collection to generate a query string :-(